# glload headers with SDL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glload

I'm setting up an OpenGL c++ program with SDL as the 'wrapper'. I noticed that as soon as I added this line:

```
#include <glload/gl_3_3.h>
#include <glload/gl_load.hpp>
```

All of the 'old' OpenGL commands such as glBegin(), glEnd() and etc. become undefined, even though I still have

```
#include <GL\GLU.h>
```

just after it. This isn't a problem as I don't intend to use them in this program at the moment, but it is a bit annoying and I was wondering if there is a way around it.

Also, why is it that I have to use

```
<glload/gl_3_3.h>
```

as opposed to

```
<glload/gl_3_3.hpp>
```

even though I am writing in C++ and not C, which seems to contradict the glsdk docs?

glsdk_0_5_2/docs/html/group__module__glload.html

Comment: Why is it annoying, if you don't intend to use them?

Comment: Because it annoys me not knowing why this breaks it, and because I may want to use them in future.

Comment: It breaks them because they are no longer part of OpenGL; they have been removed from the standard (in 3.3 there's no mention of them, and you requested 3.3 API). And no, you don't want to use them, ever.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Make this an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When requesting API of version 3.3, you request just that. As of OpenGL  3.3, `glBegin`, `glEnd`, and a lot of older fixed-pipeline functionality has been removed.

You really shouldn't be worried about it and simply code against the API version you chose; you certainly aren't going to miss any of the older functionality.